# Removing the Text Format selection

Tags: wysiwyg

Every textarea gives you an option to use either Filtered, Full, or Plain Text. Is there a way to remove or hide it so the layout becomes more streamlined? I'm using CKEditor if it means anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change who has permission to use which input format under Settings (Site Configuration) -> Input formats for Drupal 6 or Configuration -> Text formats for Drupal 7.

If you uncheck all the other options (I'm assuming the one with the editor is set as default) then the option won't appear for those users who only have the default checked.

That's at least one way.

Comment: But it appears that all roles must have access to Plain Text?

Comment: correct. See this workaround: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/how-to-disable-plain-text-for-a-specific-role

Answer (score 2):

You can also use CSS to hide the select box.

Comment: that's what I did. For reference, add this css to your custom style sheet or use "css_injector" module: .filter-wrapper {
display: none;
}